# How can I find ListVIew's source code in google?

Tags: android

I have been confused of ListView,so I want to see the source code of it.But when I get android source code. I can not find where it is.Please help me how to find ListView.java in source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/blobs/3661101005c6527dfd384d0c88c4a3b68ee208af/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java

Comment: the official site is android.git.kernel.org but it is down right now

Comment: thank you I find it ,thanks to your help.In my /home/zhangyunchen/workspaceForGit/mooncake/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget. It helps a lot

Answer (score 3):

There's a mirror on github.com. ListView is [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java).

Comment: thanks a lot ,I have found it. I just can not find which folder it is in before...aha

Answer (score 0):

Sources for most versions of the Android platform are presented at http://androidxref.com. The site has search capabilities and even allows to see version history for files. It has many features that can help e. g. searching by a class name or a file name.

Google Code Search that I used a lot for several years is no more.

Comment: Google Code Search is no longer available. :(

Comment: Fortunately, now Rodrigo Chiossi runs an OpenGrok instance at http://androidxref.com with all Android sources indexed. I will update the answer to point to it.